# PHP/PDOでMysqlに接続する

Tags: php, mysql

タイトル通りですが、phpからMySQLデータベースに接続したいのですが、
下記のようなコードを、どのディレクトリーに保存したら良いでしょうか。

```
/*接続用ステータス*/
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=●DB名●;host=●ホスト名●;charset=utf8mb4";
$User_Name = "●●●●●●";
$Password = "●●●●●●";
$Driver_Options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
];

/*接続・実行*/
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $User_Name, $Password, $Driver_Options);
}
/*エラー出力*/
catch(PDOException $PDO_ERROR){
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8', true, 500); 
    exit('DataBase ERROR/'.$PDO_ERROR->getMessage());
}
```

macOS HighSierra macOS HighSierra 10.13.6
MAMPはインストール済み。
php:7.2.1
mysql:5.638

つまらない質問ですいません。
ご回答頂けると幸いです。

Comment: タグはなるべく質問内容に関連するものだけを使用してください。必ずしも実行環境を書き連ねればいいわけではありません。今回の質問なら`phpmyadmin`と`mamp`は冗長に見えます。

Comment: 申し訳ございません。以後気をつけます。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10573

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/137420

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結局のところ Web UA がアクセスできるところ＝ http 公開ディレクトリの下のどこかに、このファイル自体を置くか、このファイルを起動するための何かを置くことになります。その際 Web UA から見た URL がどうなるかを考えて、それに合致するよう適切な場所にコピーするとか適切な場所になるようリンクを張ります。

なんだか抽象的でよくわからない説明ですが要するに設計というか運用で変わるということ。それを決めるのはあなた＝アフロ氏です。具体的な場所は設計者が適切になるよう定めるものです。

実験というか練習というか、なので接続設定が直接 php ファイル自体に書かれていますね。普通はデーターベースパスワードなど接続設定は別ファイルに追い出して http からは直接アクセスできない場所に置くものです。その設定ファイルは php からはアクセスできるようにしておかないといけません。